# C# CefSharp Offscreen mouse events, keyboard events emulating example

Tags: c#, events, mouse, cefsharp, emulation

Anybody can show me example(C#) of CefSharp.OffScreen browser mouse and keyboard events emulating? **Sorry about my english...**
For example:

> mouse down on screen x=100,y=100....move to x=200,y=200 and mouse up.
>   After press 'Enter' key.

Thanks.

Comment: The `WPF` control uses the same offscreen rendering engine, you can add some debug print statements to log what's going on. Remember to set focus. There are no examples that I'm aware of, by all means contribute some though!

Comment: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13220 is relevant, the code should be easily mapped to `CefSharp`, make sure you read both pages of the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon this `2y 6m` later and wanted to put it out to someone who might be in the same position.
Solution includes usage of `CefSharp` framework and `JavaScript` execution via `CefSharp`.

```
//1. Find the Html element x and y coordinates with something like this:

var scriptTask = _browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
    var play = document.getElementByClassName('image')[0]
    function findPos(obj)
    {
        var curleft = 0;
        var curtop = 0;

        if (obj.offsetParent)
        {
            do
            {
                curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

            return { X: curleft,Y: curtop};
        }
    }
    findPos(play)"
)
.ContinueWith(x =>
{
// 2. Continue with finding the coordinates and using MouseClick method 
// for pressing left mouse button down and releasing it at desired end position.
    var responseForMouseClick = x.Result;

    if (responseForMouseClick.Success && responseForMouseClick.Result != null)
    {
        var xy = responseForMouseClick.Result;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xy).ToString();
        var coordx = json.Substring(json.IndexOf(':') + 1, 3);
        var coordy = json.Substring(json.LastIndexOf(':') + 1, 3);

        MouseLeftDown(int.Parse(coordx) + 5, int.Parse(coordy) + 5);
        MouseLeftUp(int.Parse(coordx) + 100, int.Parse(coordy) + 100);
    }

// 3. Repeat the finding of coordinates for making focus with a click. 
// Use the HitEnter method to send the KeyEvent.
    _browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
        var objForHittingEnter = document
             .getElementsByClassName('class-name-for-hitting-enter-on')[0]
                 findPos(objForHittingEnter)") // Already defined earlier
    .ContinueWith(y =>
    {
        var responseForEnter = y.Result;

        if (responseForEnter.Success && responseForEnter.Result != null)
        {
            var xy = responseForEnter.Result;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xy).ToString();
            var coordx = json.Substring(json.IndexOf(':') + 1, 3);
            var coordy = json.Substring(json.LastIndexOf(':') + 1, 3);

            HitEnter(int.Parse(coordx) + 2, int.Parse(coordy) + 2);
        }
    });
});


public void MouseLeftDown(int x, int y)
{
    _browser.GetBrowser().GetHost()
        .SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
    Thread.Sleep(15);
}

public void MouseLeftUp(int x, int y)
{
    _browser.GetBrowser().GetHost()
        .SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
    Thread.Sleep(15);
}

public void HitEnter(int x, int y)
{
    KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent
    {
        WindowsKeyCode = 0x0D, // Enter
        FocusOnEditableField = true,
        IsSystemKey = false,
        Type = KeyEventType.KeyDown
    };

    _browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    k = new KeyEvent
    {
        WindowsKeyCode = 0x0D, // Enter
        FocusOnEditableField = true,
        IsSystemKey = false,
        Type = KeyEventType.KeyUp
    };

    _browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);

    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Special thanks to the following posts:

- [CefSharp webpage element click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680724/cefsharp-webpage-element-click)
- [Issue With CefSharp Browser SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736904/issue-with-cefsharp-browser-sendkeys)
- [CEF Simulate Mousedown and Keysend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135070/cef-simulate-mousedown-and-keysend)