# Issue With CefSharp Browser SendKeys

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am using chromium browser to automate some task.

Basically I want to load images for that I have to click "Add Image" anchor tag on the webpage.

So I cannot directly click it not sure why when other works with same code. But I have managed to bring the focus on that anchor tag but sending :

```
 KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent();
 k.WindowsKeyCode = 9;  // TAB KEY
 browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k); 
 //browser = ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
```

The above work perfectly fine as i see it coming to the correct anchor Tag.

Now i  do :

```
 KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent();
 k.WindowsKeyCode = 13;   //ENTER KEY
 browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);
```

To simulate enter key , however nothing happens but if I press "Enter" manually on Keyword it works fine so why the above is not acting same as me clicking "Enter Key"

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used your code like this, and it works for me.

```
KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent();
k.WindowsKeyCode = 0x0D;
k.FocusOnEditableField = true;
k.IsSystemKey = false;
k.Type = KeyEventType.Char;
Browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! If I wanted to replace setting the HEX value with rather a char, is that possible? Also would love to differentiate from 'd' (68) vs 'D' (100).

Answer (score 5):

So much time spent, but found the accepted answer useful to get to the bottom of this:

```
KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent
{
    WindowsKeyCode = 0x0D, // Enter
    FocusOnEditableField = true,
    IsSystemKey = false,
    Type = KeyEventType.KeyDown
};

_browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);

Thread.Sleep(100);

k = new KeyEvent
{
    WindowsKeyCode = 0x0D, // Enter
    FocusOnEditableField = true,
    IsSystemKey = false,
    Type = KeyEventType.KeyUp
};

_browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(k);

Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Notice the `KeyEventType.KeyDown` and then `KeyEventType.KeyUp` is sent.

Inspired by [CEF Simulate Mousedown and Keysend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135070/cef-simulate-mousedown-and-keysend) and [CefSharp webpage element click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680724/cefsharp-webpage-element-click).

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! If I wanted to replace setting the HEX value with rather a char, is that possible? Also would love to differentiate from 'd' (68) vs 'D' (100)