# cefsharp send tab key - undesired behavior

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Hi I'm new to cefsharp and am quite enjoy working with it. One thing I ran into is, when I use the code to send TAB key hoping to traverse the webpage, it doesn't behave like human tabbing.

The base code I'm using is the winforms code from here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

For example, when I added this code after the browser has been initialized with google search page:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            CefSharp.KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent();

            keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode = (int)Keys.Tab;
            keyEvent.FocusOnEditableField = true;
            keyEvent.IsSystemKey = false;
            keyEvent.Type = KeyEventType.Char;
            browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(keyEvent);
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
```

What I'm expecting is like manual tabbing through the screen, with one of the page elements focused each time, in the order of their position on the page.

However what I found is the tabbing doesn't seem to be happening on the webpage, until when I click inside of the search box, it adds on tabs inside the box. With manual tabbing the focus will leave the search box. When I set focus to another page element (the image above for example), it doesn't seem to lose focus with the program keeping tabbing.

Any instruction will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure... have you tried setting WindowsKeyCode as 0x09 ? (Hex value of tab)

Comment: @PiGi78 Yes I tried 0x09, it's the same result.

Comment: First I'd suggest you start by reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input to get some background. Then try https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452094/4583726

Comment: @amaitland thank you, by following the solution I was able to achieve the correct functionality.

Comment: Great, if you can post an answer with an example of your code to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's working code for my own solution. There are two methods, one is for string, one is for special keys. I have not done extensive testing so it may not fit all situations:

```
public static async Task SendStringToBrowser(this IWebBrowser browser, string sData)
{            

    var charArray = sData.ToCharArray();

    foreach (char c in charArray)
    {
        CefSharp.KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent();

        keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode = (int)c;
        keyEvent.FocusOnEditableField = true;
        keyEvent.IsSystemKey = false;
        keyEvent.Type = KeyEventType.Char;
        browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(keyEvent);

        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}

public static async Task SendKeyToBrowser(this IWebBrowser browser, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
{
    
    CefSharp.KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent();

    keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode = (int)key;
    keyEvent.FocusOnEditableField = true;
    keyEvent.IsSystemKey = false;
    keyEvent.Type = KeyEventType.KeyDown;
    browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(keyEvent);

    await Task.Delay(50);

    keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode = (int)key;
    keyEvent.FocusOnEditableField = true;
    keyEvent.IsSystemKey = false;
    keyEvent.Type = KeyEventType.KeyUp;
    browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(keyEvent);
    await Task.Delay(50);

}
```

To send a string to browser, do:

```
await browser.SendStringToBrowser(sDataToSend);
```

To send a special key to browser, do:

```
await browser.SendKeyToBrowser(Keys.Tab);
```